# skip rows with bad dates while using pd.read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading in csv files from an external data source using `pd.read_csv`, as in the code below:

```
pd.read_csv(
    BytesIO(raw_data),
    parse_dates=['dates'],
    date_parser=np.datetime64,
)
```

However, somewhere in the csv that's being sent, there is a misformatted date, resulting in the following error:

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "2015-08-2" at position 8
```

This causes the entire application to crash. Of course, I can handle this case with a try/except, but then I will lose all the other data in that particular csv. I need pandas to keep and parse that other data.

I have no way of predicting when/where this data (which changes daily) will have badly formatted dates. Is there some way to get `pd.read_csv` to skip only the rows with bad dates but to still parse all the other rows in the csv?

Comment: check `skiprows` parameter of [`read_cvs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). You could pass a list of row numbers with bad date, but you need to know row numbers.

Comment: what are the potential formats?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> somewhere in the csv that's being sent, there is a misformatted date

[`np.datetime64`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html) needs [ISO8601 formatted](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) strings to work properly. The good news is that you can wrap `np.datetime64` in your own function and use this as the `date_parser`:

```
def parse_date(v):
   try:
      return np.datetime64(v)
   except:
      # apply whatever remedies you deem appropriate
      pass
   return v

   pd.read_csv(
     ...
     date_parser=parse_date
   )
```

> I need pandas to keep and parse that other data.

I often find that a more flexible date parser like [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) works better than `np.datetime64` and may even work without the extra function:

```
import dateutil
pd.read_csv(
    BytesIO(raw_data),
    parse_dates=['dates'],
    date_parser=dateutil.parser.parse,
)
```

Comment: downvote all you like, please add a comment so I can improve the answer. thank you.

Comment: I don't want to change the core functionality of the code. I need to use `np.datetime64` for project-specific reasons, so that needs to stay.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to downvote. Other than the suggestion to move away from `np.datetime64`, this is a good solution. Thanks!

Comment: @LateCoder I see, updated to reflect your requirement better

Comment: For completeness: `dateutil.parser.parse` is the default parser used by `pd.read_csv`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this using pd.convert_objects() method:

```
# make good and bad date csv files
# read in good dates file using parse_dates - no problem
df = pd.read_csv('dategood.csv', parse_dates=['dates'], date_parser=np.datetime64)

df.dtypes

dates    datetime64[ns]
data            float64
dtype: object

# try same code on bad dates file - throws exceptions
df = pd.read_csv('datebad.csv', parse_dates=['dates'], date_parser=np.datetime64)

ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "Q%Bte0tvk5" at position 0

# read the file first without converting dates
# then use convert objects to force conversion
df = pd.read_csv('datebad.csv')
df['cdate'] = df.dates.convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')

# resulting new date column is a datetime64 same as good data file
df.dtype

dates            object
data            float64
cdate    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

# the bad date has NaT in the cdate column - can clean it later
df.head()

        dates      data      cdate
0  2015-12-01  0.914836 2015-12-01
1  2015-12-02  0.866848 2015-12-02
2  2015-12-03  0.103718 2015-12-03
3  2015-12-04  0.514086 2015-12-04
4  Q%Bte0tvk5  0.583617        NaT
```

Comment: Now `convert_objects` is deprecated, but you may use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for `errors='coerce'` feature.

Answer (score 0):

use inbuilt `pd.to_datetime`, which converts the non date type data to `NaT`

```
pd.read_csv(
    BytesIO(raw_data),
    parse_dates=['dates'],
    date_parser=pd.to_datetime,
)
```

Now you can filter out the invalid rows with standard nan/ null check

```
df = df[~df["dates"].isnull()]
```

Comment: You need to set errors='coerce' parameter to pd.to_datetime. By default it will raise an exception when invalid date is found. With coerce, the invalid dates are converted to NaT. So for example `date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')`